# appending results to array after parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing, f#

Some eloquency questions:

A. How to add a list that was formed from parallel processing directly to the a Concurrent results array in an eloquent way.

```
let results = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<string>()
let tasks = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>()
tasks.add("a")
tasks.add("b")

let answers = tasks
        |> Seq.map asyncRequest
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> Array.toList

Array.append results answers
```

**Attempt** Is there a way to append via pipe operator?

```
let answers = tasks
        |> Seq.map asyncRequest
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> Array.append results
```

---

B. Is there a way to add items via List constructor?

```
let tasks = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>()
tasks.add("a")
tasks.add("b")
```

---

C. Is there a way to construct a queue from array using Queue constructor?

```
let items: string[] = [|"a", "b", "c"|]
let jobs = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<string>()

items |> Array.map jobs.Enqueue |> ignore
```

Comment: I think you better ask all these questions here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f

Comment: I don't see an option to post a message there. I can see the chat room. I think I'm not authorized in the chat room

Comment: @Developer11 - [You need to have at least 20 reputation points to talk in chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat), so you should be able to. When I clicked on the chat room, there was a big bar across the bottom of the screen with a text box and two buttons: "Send" and "Upload...". The "Send" button would post a chat message. Do you see that bar and those buttons when you click on the chat room? If you don't, something unusual is going on. **Update:** Never mind, just noticed that you posted several times in that chat room, so apparently you figured it out.

Comment: yes initially, the problem was clicking on the notification took me to chat transcript that doesn't offer sending a message, only going through all rooms and then F# worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A.** you can't use `Array.append` on `results`, because `results` is a `ConcurrentBag`, but `Array.append` expects its argument to be an `Array`. To add stuff to `ConcurrentBag`, use its [`Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394995(v=vs.110).aspx). Add items one by one:

```
tasks
    |> Seq.map asyncRequest
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> Array.iter results.Add
```

Adding items one by one is a little inefficient. If your `ConcurrentBag` is really created right in the same function, as your example shows, you may consider using its [constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381771(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
let answers = tasks
    |> Seq.map asyncRequest
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously

let results = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<string>( answers )
```

**B.** yes, there is a way to add stuff to a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`. This class provides [a handy `Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose:

```
tasks.Add "a"
tasks.Add "b"
```

Enclosing the argument in parentheses (as in your attempt) is not necessary, but allowed:

```
tasks.Add("a")
tasks.Add("b")
```

**C.** yes, there is a way to construct a queue from an array. The `Queue` class has [a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69zckb8z(v=vs.110).aspx), and arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can call that constructor on an array:

```
let jobs = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<string>( items )
```

---

**Please note** that you hardly needed my help to get any of the above information. Everything is freely available on MSDN (see links above) or from autocompletion/intellisense in your favorite code editor.